# Secure temporary storage

Tags: security, data

I'm trying to find a way to securely store data for the duration of a session - specifically it's for passwords on a jump box - so the user only needs to enter the password for a given target once in their jump-box session. Ideally I'd want to hide the data even from root.

Although I trust the people with root access, I don't necessarily trust all the programs which run as root - e.g. backups which might expose the data.

SELinux won't do - the policies available on RHEL would need a lot of work, it's not portable, and, of course, [SELinux sucks](https://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2016/11/selinux-sucks.html).

Encryption won't work - then I need to work out where to store the key.

Running a daemon and putting the data in there / authenticating using socket credential passing, however there is some effort in implementing this, and I would like to be confident that the data was purged at the end of the session (which may not always end cleanly).

Using O_TMPFILE to create an un-named file looks like it solves a lot of problems of populating the data and cleaning up at the end of the session. But how can another process get access to the data? I suppose the answer would be to have the owning process also open a listening socket and handle requests that way - but is there an easier solution?

Should I be rethinking this completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the kernel keyring (and, in particular, the `keyctl` command) to store your data in a secure way.

The kernel keyring has enough granularity to store keys that are available for a specific user or even for a specific session (so if you're connected using SSH and on the console, or using SSH from two different machines, the sessions will be separate from each other.)

A sample example usage is:

```
$ keyctl add user mypassword supersecret @s
543456789
```

The kernel stored a key named "mypassword", with value "supersecret", only on the session (`@s`, consider also `@u` for the user keyring.)

You can use the `padd` command to read from stdin instead:

```
$ echo -n supersecret | keyctl padd user mypassword @s
543456789
```

Then when you need to retrieve it:

```
$ keyctl print 543456789
supersecret
```

If you want to look it up from its description ("mypassword"), you can use the `search` command to do so:

```
$ keyctl search @s user mypassword
543456789
```

(And then use the ID of the key to print it using `keyctl print`.)

There is a lot more that the keyring can do... If you want to use it, maybe start by reading through the [man page of keyctl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/keyctl) which might give you a good idea of what operations are supported and of which keyring to use.

Comment: I've started reading the docs - I'd not come across the kernel keyring before. Interesting and a few pitfalls to trap the unwary - but it seems a sensible and well thought out mechanism.